# Angular: Create two columns by count

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

The code below is creating two columns based off of even and odd.  What would I change so instead of even and odd it displays the first 8 results in column one and the remainder in column two?

```html
<div *ngFor="let year of userYear; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf='i%2 === 0' class="float-left left-column push-left"><span>{{year}}</span></div>
     <div *ngIf='i%2 !== 0' class="float-left right-column"><span>{{year}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont really know what you want exactly, but it sounds your are looking for `*ngIf="i < 8"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `i%2 === 0` to `i < 8` and `i%2 !== 0` to `i >= 8`:

```
<div *ngFor="let year of userYear; let i = index">
     <div *ngIf='i < 8' class="float-left left-column push-left"><span>{{year}}</span></div>
     <div *ngIf='i >= 8' class="float-left right-column"><span>{{year}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and pardon Im not able to vote this up or accept this answer due to my new account; only has 13 points.  But I accept this answer!

Comment: You can accept answer even if you can't vote this up: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers